# How to publish ROS program?

Tags: ros, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like windows programs, hos to publish a single simple "setup" install package on ROS so that I can reduce server configuration work when transfer to other machine?
Is anyone has experience on this issue? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198418/how-to-publish-ros-program?/) by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2014-11-27**:
I mean, a single and simple ROS install program file .

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-27**:
Are you looking for windows versions or which system? Because in ubuntu it's just `apt-get ros-indigo-desktop-full`.

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2014-11-27**:
No, I mean, I made a ROS project on developing machine, and I want to transfer my ROS project to any other new business machines which is under ubuntu system, and I won't build the code again. how could I do to transfer the project easily like windows "One click install" program?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-27**:
If the systems are binary compatible, after `caktin_make install` it should be sufficient to just copy the `install` directory and source the contained setup.sh in the user's setup. I'm not aware of any tools that do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no "one click install" for ROS as far as I know. You could always send a virtual machine or look at solutions like ansible. We have some ansible configs available [here](https://github.com/shadow-robot/sr-build-tools) if you're interested. It's a work in progress, mostly for internal use so it's not fully documented but it should hopefully help you get started.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2014-11-27**:
Thanks, dear Ugo, is there any other solution? Whether a simple shell script can solve the transfer problem or not?

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2015-04-22**:
Sorry for the long delay in answering. If you're still looking for a shell script solution we have something like this (https://github.com/shadow-robot/sr-build-tools/blob/master/bin/sr-install-indigo-source). You'll need to modify it to reflect your install obviously. Cheers